# What is the best way work with related, hierarchical data in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Objective-C.
I'd like to know the best way to work with related and/or hierarchical data.
Is there a 'record' or 'struct' equivalent?
Would I just use a Class?

My data is pretty simple - let's say it's a person with 5 attributes of varying type:
NSString, int, float, UIColor, BOOL

I'll then need to create instances, hold them (an array most likely), and eventually store them using (most likely) CoreData.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, a class with attributes.  objective-c and core data were made exactly for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI your question's answer is inside your description ;)

short and sweet : CoreData is great choice.

Comment: I don't think Core Data, while extremely neat, is a good suggestion for people new to ObjC...

Comment: Nothing is very hard nwdays, just open iTunes U and find world's best university lecturer's lectures to learn any thing ;) and one day OP has to learn it so why not now ;)

Comment: Why not now? Imagine a marathon runner wannabe with almost no running skills starting in a marathon ;)

Answer (score 0):

use an NSDictionary for store simple information (one or two field) and Class for more complex.
If you need to save them in a persistent storage use coredata or plist files.

Comment: giving core data and plist equality might be dangerous...Coredata is for high end persistence storage and plist is just to store minor settings. so basically plist isn't an option with core data because they both are totally different very different :)

Comment: yes, you're right.I think that coredata is a bit complex for people that are new to iOS programming.

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C, but not new to databases and programming in general.